# Loop_expression in 'for' statement in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, loops

Is it possible to put 'x/10' as a loop_expression in 'for' statement as following:

```
for ( ; numberD != 0 ; x / 10) {
    resultNumber = numberD / x;
    NSLog (@"Display %i", resultNumber);
    numberD /= 10;
}
```

I tried to run this way, but it fails to do it.
Any suggestions of how to do it, if I need the loop to divide x by 10 every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but I believe your operator is wrong.

```
for ( ; numberD != 0 ; x /= 10) {
    resultNumber = numberD / x;
    NSLog (@"Display %i", resultNumber);
    numberD /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Spell it out and life will be much better. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say better use a while loop instead if for loop.

```
 while(numberD != 0) {
   resultNumber = numberD / x;
   NSLog (@"Display %i", resultNumber);
   numberD /= 10;
   x /= 10;
 }
```